# Como hacer setNestedScrollView en versiones anteriores a Lollipop?

Tags: android, xml

Me gustaria poder hacer un `NestedScrollView` adaptado a versiones anteriores a `Lollipop (API 21)` y estoy intentando seguir el siguiente tutorial:

http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/

pero sigo sin conseguir hacer scroll en el texto, uso un framework muy sencillo y que no da problemas si uso el metodo `setNestedScrollView` para Lollipop o superior:

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

A continuacion dejo mi codigo para que se pueda corregir mi error:

-------->   ***item_image_parallax2.xml***

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingTop="24dp">


                        <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView
                            android:id="@+id/dv"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="75dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">

                        </com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </FrameLayout>
```

Digamos que el xml de arriba lo utilizo en un Viewgroup conjunto a otro XML que dejo a continuacion:

------------------>      ***header.xml***

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listViewId"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Utilizo el codigo siguiente en la actividad (extends de AppCompatActivity):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image_parallax2, list, false);
        image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.image);
        list.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Comment: @MMariscal Si usas las librerías de soporte puedes utilizar sin ningun problema NestedScrollView en versiones pre-lollipop, cual es el problema que presenta? Podrías agregar una imagen de lo que sucede por favor.

Comment: Digamos que no se como colocar en el xml (el orden correcto) para poder hacer scroll en el texto y que no de problemas, el problema es que no puedo hacer scroll en el CardView aun estando NestedScrollView en el xml... Gracias por contestarme TODAS las preguntas que hago, lo sabes todo, que envidia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo algún problema en el Layout, no puedes ver que se realiza el scroll ya que tienes solo un elemento y además solo tiene una altura de `75dp`:

```
   <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView
                            android:id="@+id/dv"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="75dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">

                        </com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView>
```

Para probar que se realiza correctamente el scroll cambia `android:layout_height` a unos 1000dp :

```
   <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView
      ...         
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
   </com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como conclusión tu layout es correcto y puede realizar el scroll vertical.

Comment: Y hacer scroll de un elemento (Mi DocumentView) comprimido el height a 75dp, cual es la correcta implementacion? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo siento pero aun me sigue sin funcionar... Algo hago mal...

Comment: Pregunta actualizada, muchas gracias!

Comment: @M.Mariscal Simplemente si agregas un scrollview vertical y la altura puede contener sin problema a todos los elementos nunca va a generar el scroll. Te sugiero pruebas haciendo menos alto el CardView con android:layout_height="50dp" para que veas lo que te comento. Por lo que veo el CardView debe estar adentro y debe contener el documentView.

Comment: Vale ya esta... solucionado! SI QUE HACIA SCROLL DESDE SIEMPRE! lo malo que debes de tener un dedo presionando en el cardview, y el otro arrastrando de arriba a abajo y viceversa, necesitare configurar el scroll si quiero hacerlo en el cardview... jeje

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @Elenasys, no lo hubiese solucionado sin tu ayuda!

Comment: Hola que bien me da gusto, así es el Scroll se puede hacer pero no se activa porque no es necesario ya que tu DocumentView cabía dentro de la pantalla, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

SOLUCIONADO!

No me podia ir a dormir sin hacerlo... Digamos que el problema que me daba antes, era que si que podia hacer scroll pero con un dedo presionar el texto y con el otro tirar arriba o abajo para hacer scroll... ahora ya lo hace como debe de hacerlo, si presionas con un dedo en el texto y arrastras se mueve, la logica de TextView de cualquier texto que no puedes ver... os dejo el codigo XML a continuacion:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="20dp">

                <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView
                    android:id="@+id/dv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Espero que le sirva de curiosidad a alguien!